# Creating a network of nodes where there are multiple paths and a continuous link

Tags: netlogo

I have managed to create a set of nodes and link them. However most of the time the nodes that generated do not form a continuous link with each other. By that I mean, for example if 8 nodes are generated (N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8). 
Connection maybe N1-N3-N5,
and another set N2-N4-N6-N8-N7. I want both sets to have some sort of connection, i.e N5-N7. So that if I were to run a nw extenstion function, such as  nw:turtles-on-path-to, I wont get an error saying it can find the path from N3 to N8.
ideally I would also like if some of the nodes are connected to more than one node, for example N2-N4, N2-N6, N2-N5.
Any ideas how to do it? Thanks in advance

```
breed [nodes node]
create-nodes 30[
set color blue
set size 1.5
set shape"circle"
]
ask nodes [create-link-with one-of other nodes]

repeat 500 [layout-spring nodes link 0.2 5 1]
ask nodes [setxy 0.95 * xcor * 0.95 ycor]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that you don't have enough edges. You have N edges with N nodes (because each node is asked to add one edge). You need N-1 edges just to create a chain, so you only have one spare to create an extra connection.

Once you have enough edges, you can then do some sort of rewiring where you check if there's more than one component (`nw:weak-component-clusters`) and, if so, create an edge between a randomly selected node in one cluster to a randomly selected node in another cluster (and delete a random edge if you want to maintain the same total number of edges). Keep doing that (`while`) until you only have one component.

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with the term edge. Are you to one of  the inputs in layout-springs?

Comment: edge is the same as link. It is a more generic term from network analysis rather than a NetLogo term.